# Почему из searchform.php переходит на index.php? search.php есть!

Tags: wordpress

`searchform.php`

```
<form class="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
    <span class="search__wrapper">
        <span class="search__img"></span>
    </span>
    <input class="search__body" placeholder="Поиск по проектам" name="search" value="<?php if(!$_GET['search']){echo $_GET['search'];}?>"/>
</form>
```

`page-projects.php`

```
// Код страницы

<?php get_search_form(); ?>

// Код страницы
```

`search.php`

```
<?php get_header();?>
    <div class="frame catalog">
        <hr class="line"/>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/breadcrumbs')?>
        <h2 class="caption about__caption"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <p class="subcaption"><?php the_subtitle();?></p>
        <div class="catalog__search">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
        <main id="catalog__main" class="catalog__main">
            <?php
                if (have_posts()) :
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        ?>
                        <div id="posts">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                            <div id="post_info">
                                <div>Автор: <?php the_author() ?></div>
                                <div>Дата добавления: <?php the_date() ?></div>
                                <div id="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                            <span>Категория: <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php
                else :
                    echo "Извините по Вашему результату ничего не найдено";
                endif;
            ?>
        </main>
    </div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

`index.php`

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php echo 'index'?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

При поиске:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы переходил на search.php?

Comment: А в какой папке search.php? Должен быть в корне темы.

Answer (score 0):

обязательно должен присутствовать параметр s (что искать): `<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />`

Comment: `<input id="s" class="search__body" placeholder="Поиск по проектам" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>"/>` Все равно переходит на index.php

Comment: Стандартный поиск  <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ) ?>" >
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Поиск: </label>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" id="s" />
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="найти" />
</form>

Comment: В корне находится. Не могу разобраться, в том то и дело. Вроде все правильно, а нет, не работает